# Setting variable in an if statement

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have started Roaslind, the bioinformatics-teaching platform. I am trying to do the first problem. This is the code that I have ended up with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -tt

def count_nuc():

    '''Usage: count_nuc()'''

    s = raw_input('Enter nucleotide string: ')
    if s.isalpha():        
        if len(s) < 1000:
            for letter in s:
                if letter.upper() == 'A':
                    a =  s.count('A')
                elif letter.upper() == 'C':
                    c =  s.count('C')
                elif letter.upper() == 'G':
                    g = s.count('G')
                elif letter.upper() == 'T':
                    t = s.count('T')
                else:
                    print('Error')
            print '%d %d %d %d' % (a, c, g, t)
        else:
            print('String must be 1000 nucleotides or less.')
            count_nuc()
    else:
        print('String must of nucleotides must only contain alphabetic characters.')
        count_nuc()
```

It works fine. Mostly. the issue that I am having is kind of silly. I am using the count method for strings to count the number of nucleotides of a specific type, then assigning that number to my variable. However, if no such nucleotide exists (i.e., I give it a string like 'ATGTTT', then my variable 'c' never gets defined and the print statement barfs. I have thought about this and nothing I can think of allows me to get around this. I have thought of trying to check if the variable exists before printing it out, but this seems kind of clumsy to me and am not sure if that would be considered proper coding etiquette.

Comment: Note that you are counting *all* A's for *every* A in the string, which is rather wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution might be assigning all variables to zero before the loop.

For example:

`a = c = g = t = 0`

Comment: They're counts, so `0` rather than `''`, but initialising is good.

Answer (score 3):

Your counting algorithm is doing a lot more work than necessary. You count all the `"A"`s in your sequence every time you see an `"A"` while you are iterating. Instead, you could skip the iteration and just do each of the counts once unconditionally (if you count something that doesn't appear in the string, you'll get a `0`):

```
if len(s) < 1000:
    a = s.count('A')
    c = s.count('C')
    g = s.count('G')
    t = s.count('T')
    print '%d %d %d %d' % (a, c, g, t)
```

If you want to do the counting manually, you need to change your assignments. Initialize the variables to `0`, then add one to the appropriate one when you see the relevant letter:

```
if len(s) < 1000:
    a = c = g = t = 0
    for letter in s:
        if letter.upper() == 'A':
            a += 1
        elif letter.upper() == 'C':
            c += 1
        elif letter.upper() == 'G':
            g += 1
        elif letter.upper() == 'T':
            t += 1
        else:
            print('Error')
    print '%d %d %d %d' % (a, c, g, t)
```

Or, better yet, let [Python's standard library do the counting for you](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

if len(s) < 1000:
    counts = Counter(s)
    print "{A} {C} {G} {T}".format(counts)
```

Comment: Thank you for your insightful critique. I have only been doing this about a week so far and have never heard of collections or Counter, but your solution does seem to save a lot of typing. Thank you very much for your kind input to a beginner's query.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
a = s.count('A') if letter.upper() == 'A' else 0
```

to move the logic "inline".